# Filing 1120S for business that was shut down in 2015 and had no activity in 2016

Tags: united-states, taxes, business, s-corporation

My business shut down in 2015 and had zero income or activity in 2016. It was an S-corp. The 1120S taxes for 2015 were filed in March of 2016.

My assumption was I could simply file the tax return myself with zero income and be done with it, but then I began wondering if there could be some reason it could be more complicated than that.

Is there something I could be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First off, **consult a CPA**.

---

According to [TurboTax](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/IRS-Tax-Return/Can-I-File-an-Income-Tax-Return-if-I-Don-t-Have-Any-Income-/INF14238.html), it is perfectly legal to final as an individual with zero income. But, alas, according to [Entities](https://www.irs.gov/help-resources/tools-faqs/faqs-for-individuals/frequently-asked-tax-questions-answers/small-business-self-employed-other-business/entities/entities-4), by the IRS, you **must file** as a partnership or a corporation even if you have zero income.

As for my two cents, I can only see it being advantageous for filing on expense purposes, but as you have no income, the point is mute.
Hope it all goes over well as the forms are due March 15.